# Помогите создать функцию с переменным возвращением значения

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Создать функцию «переключатель» toggleMe(), которая при вызове чередует возвращаемые булевы значения (true, false)

Comment: можно приступать?

Comment: @Igor Это сарказм? Помогите хотя бы с помощью чего реализовать. Не понимаю как оно должно возвращать разные значения. перебором?

Comment: `last = !last; return last;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function getToggleMe() {
  var last = false;
  return function() {
    last = !last;
    return last;
  };
}

var toggleMe = getToggleMe();
console.log(toggleMe());
console.log(toggleMe());
console.log(toggleMe());
console.log(toggleMe());
```